# VW Velocity 1.6i 2007 Fan not working, engine leaking out all the water

Tags: vw, golf

I was driving the weekend and pulled over heard the engine making a noise, saw there was no more water left in the car anymore, plus my fan was not working and my engine is letting out all the water through a small whole thats at the back of the engine. whats wrong besides for the fan which i now need to replace? Its a electric fan.

Thanks

Comment: Before replacing the fan, I'd look to see if the relay is bad. Always start at the easiest and work forward from there. It sounds as though you have bigger problems than a fan though. You say "*a small hole that's at the back of the engine*" ... where *exactly* is this hole? A hole leaking antifreeze is never a good thing on an engine. If the engine has overheated in this process (which is highly likely), there could be engine damage which will incur a lot of work to get fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the hole is at the back of the engine their was about a coin size imprint at the back of the engine and in the middle was this hole. its about the size of width of a screw-driver, what happened was when i pulled over its was leaking antifreeze out and the fan wasnt going on then i put in antifreeze let the car cool down, all the antifreeze i was putting in was leaking out, i put in water and i drove home and it stop letting out antifreeze through this hole. i stopped like every 5mins to put in water was i ran out of antifreeze. after a while it was letting out steam.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds as though you have a hole in a freeze plug. In most cases this can be fixed without engine removal or major work, though it will take some work to get to it and get it replaced. I would not run the engine any more until you get it fixed. A qualified mechanic should be able to take care of it for you without issue. What happens with the freeze plug is that corrosion will take place due to old/weak antifreeze. What may be a bigger issue here is if the other freeze plugs (ever engine has several) might be in the same basic condition, that is just waiting to fail.

You also need to discern what's going on with the fans. To me, they should be running. In most cases it can be tracked down to either a fuse, a relay, or possibly the temperature sending unit (sensor) as being bad. You can test the fan(s) by putting power to them directly.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, this happened the weekend and i haven't rode the car since. and mechanics will be picking it up today. thanks a lot really helpful.